# Can't install 3rd party windows service in Windows 7

Tags: .net, windows, security, service, installation

I have a 3rd party .exe installer which along everything else that it install, it includes a windows service which is started automatically after finishing:

I can't install it because it keeps saying : "server xxxx failed to start, . Verify that you have sufficient privileges to start system services. Now, i've tried several things:

- run as admin
- re-starting RPC and win installer services
- unregister and register msiexec via cmd
- adding the user to log as service policy in local policies
- installing frameworks 4.5,4

and many others...

Curious is that it is installing right in a windows 10 build, but not on a brand new Windows 7 build x86 and x64.

as this is a "closed" .exe from a 3rd party I even tried a brand new custom windows service with a dummy exe and it's working.

thanks a lot

Comment: The error message you get is generic and can appear in multiple problems related to installing services. In most cases the service itself is not supported to run on the OS, maybe something in the code ??? Check with the company that built it to see if they officially support it on Win 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by running the installation process bypassing the windows UAC and kind of impersonating an elevated user.

The following fix refers to Windows Vista, but i've tried with success on W8.1 and W10.

[Start process and bypass UAC](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35773/Subverting-Vista-UAC-in-Both-and-bit-Archite)

[Similar answer on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125341/how-do-you-do-impersonation-in-net/7250145#7250145)